# Can't install app from Play Store since NativeScript 5.1

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am having an issue when I publish my apps on Google Play store since I updated to NS 5.1/Angular 7. I am not an expert with the AndroidManifest.xml file but I will show you what I have added maybe you can figure out what is going on.

This is my old AndroidManifest.xml used in NS 4.X:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="__PACKAGE__" android:versionCode="2070" android:versionName="2.0.7">
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="__APILEVEL__" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <activity android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is the new one I am using with NS 5.1/Angular 7:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="__PACKAGE__" android:versionCode="2101" android:versionName="2.1.1">
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="__APILEVEL__" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.*.*.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" tools:replace="android:resource" />
        </provider>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Also, I have added these lines to app.gradle file:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "26.+"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since I am using this configuration, the app does not install on my Samsung Galaxy A Tablet.

[image: Play Store can not install the app]

Also, in some apps it shows a message saying: `This app may not be optimized for your device.` Not this case.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Check this thread that suggest that the issue is related to SD card problem https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/204469/why-is-play-store-showing-cant-install-app-error-code-910

Answer (score 0):

I think is because your android support version. The latest version of Nativescript uses 28 so try to remove that change from your gradle